# Extract More Than Two Dimensions via Python: sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA & transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transform

I am very interested in using Python to extract 3-4 Dimensions via Canonical Correlation Analyses. I am pasting my very basic code below, and it appears to always default to only extracting two Dimensions even though each of my input arrays are 10,000+ X 3. Even if I have 4 columns for my X & Y matrices it always gives just two Dimensions - was hoping for three and eventually four as I add many more raw Features to my X and Y arrays. Trying to keep simple for now. Could part of my problem also be that some of my Field Names have spaces in them too?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = "G:\Shared drives\Data Intelligence\ZF\Segmentation/Data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data)
df.head()
print(df.columns)

X = df[['Altcurr Ext Stk Sales Cc',\
        'Altcurr Ext Dss Sales Cc',\
        'LBM Sales']]
X.head()
X_mc = (X-X.mean())/(X.std())
X_mc.head()

Y = df[['Primary_Supplier_0_org1',\
        'Primary_Supplier_1_org2',\
        'Primary_Supplier_2_TV']]
Y.head()

Y_mc = (Y-Y.mean())/(Y.std())
Y_mc.head()

from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA

ca = CCA()
ca.fit(X_mc, Y_mc)
X_c, Y_c = ca.transform(X_mc, Y_mc)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the CCA() function sets , you can check out the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA) :

```
Parameters:
n_components int, default=2
Number of components to keep. Should be in [1, min(n_samples, n_features, n_targets)].
```

For your dataset, X and Y both have 3 columns, so you can go up to `n_components = 3` . Using an example dataset :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=3, n_features=6,random_state=0)

y = X[:,3:]
X = X[:,:3]

ca = CCA(n_components = 3)
ca.fit(X, y)
X_c, Y_c = ca.transform(X, y)

print(X_c.shape)
(10000, 3)
print(Y_c.shape)
(10000, 3)
```